Writing data from AWS Glue to a Postgres table
I would like to insert a row from AWS Glue into a patient table in Postgres.
The flow is the following:
AWS Flow
If I run the job it is working but it is inserting the data only in the AWS Glue table, not in Postgres.
The problem is that I do not know where to specify the connection to use in order to insert the data in Postgres.
The properties for the target are the followings:
Target Properties
In case I would use a Redshift DB as a target I see that I can specify the connection:
Redshift Properties
For the Oracle, the same as for Postgres, nothing to specify, only local AWS Glue DB:
Oracle Properties
They seems to be the same: Oracle and Posgtres. What is the difference?
I have defined a connection to Postgres that is working fine for retrieving data from PG and inserted it into CSV files using AWS Glue.
I do not know how to use this connection to insert data from AWS Glue to Postgres.
Thanks :)
